# Is the direct sum of two orthogonal subspaces well defined in infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let's say that $V$ is an inner product space on some field $\Bbb{K}$ and $M$ is a subspace of $V$. If $M^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal complement of $M$ with respect to the inner product, can I make the statement that

$$
V=M\oplus M^{\perp}
$$
if the dimension of $V$ is not specified to be finite, or even countable? In other words, is the direct sum well defined between orthogonal subspaces in an infinite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: The direct sum $M \oplus M^\perp$ is well-defined. It need not be equal to $V$, though. If $V$ is complete and $M$ is closed, then you have $V = M \oplus M^\perp$.

Comment: I am applying that to Hilbert spaces, so yes. I thought that subspaces were always closed though, even in the infinite-dimensional case. Anyway, is it much difficult, or even long, to prove?

Comment: No, if you consider $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, the proper subspace of the sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms is dense, so it's not closed. It's not very difficult to prove (the part that you have a direct sum $M\oplus M^\perp$ is very easy, that that direct sum is $V$ if $M$ is closed and $V$ complete is a bit of work). Once you have the projection lemma, the rest is immediate.

Comment: I have given a proof of the projection lemma [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/903095/83702).

Comment: Alright, thank you. I must admit I know nothing about the implications of infinite-dimensionality. As I really need to know more (I'll need to study representations of Lie groups and algebras on infinite dimensional, even non separable Hilbert spaces, just to make an example), would you be so kind to suggest any reading on the subject? (If it's not too much to ask).

Comment: Literature recommendations are always a weak point for me. You would need to read (at least parts of) some book on Functional Analysis, but I'm not sure what might be a good choice for you. If you like Rudin's style, his "Functional Analysis" is of course a worthwhile read. But there are lots of good books on FA, I suggest you look at a couple and pick one whose style suits you.

Comment: So isn't this an algebraic subject? Thank you anyway.

Comment: @GiorgioComitini it is far more often approached from an analytic perspective.  Anyway, Kreyzig's Functional Analysis is a good, readable first step into infinite-dimensionality.