# Is the span of a in infinite list of orthogonal vectors in $L^2$ closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, lp-spaces

I was wondering if the span of a countably infinite list ${f_n}$ of orthonormal vectors in $L^2$ is closed. I just came across the first comment on this post [Is the direct sum of two orthogonal subspaces well defined in infinite-dimensional vector spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1352418/is-the-direct-sum-of-two-orthogonal-subspaces-well-defined-in-infinite-dimension). It says says "The direct sum $M \oplus M^\perp$ is well-defined. It need not be equal to $V$, though. If $V$ is complete and $M$ is closed, then you have $V=M \oplus M^\perp$".

I really don't know how to show that the span of these vectors is closed or open. I'll appreciate any guidence.

Comment: What, precisely, is the span of a countable set of vectors?

Comment: The second comment from Daniel Fischer in that linked post gives an example: if you take $e^{(n)} := (0,\dots,0,1,0\dots,0,\dots)$ with $1$ being at the $n$-th place, then the span of the family $(e^{(n)})_n$ is a subspace of $\ell^2$ that is not $\ell^2$ itself and is dense in $\ell^2$, therefore it cannot be closed.

Comment: @kimchilover, in my own experience and use, "span" means specifically _algebraic_ span, that is, _finite_ linear combinations... no limiting processes, no topological closure...

Comment: @paulgarrett  In mine, too.  But I'd like an exact statement of the original question.

Comment: This is my first time reading about infinite vector spaces. I've read that a span of a countable set of vectors is the set of all linear combinations of finitely many vectors.